# How do I filter out links and js codes using angularjs $sce

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs version 1.6.4

I have written this filter below

```
myFilter.$inject = ['$sce'];
export function myFilter($sce: any){
    return function(val: any) {
        val = '<marquee direction=left style="color: white; font-size: 24px; background-image: linear-gradient(to left, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red);">' 
            + val + '</marquee>' + ' <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>'
            + ' <script type="text/javascript"> console.log("wer hoch steigt der wird tief fallen"); </script>';
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    }
}
```

and I use it like this

```
<p ng-bind-html="fooHtml | myFilter"></p>
```

How is there a built-in feature in angularjs that removes hrefs and javascript codes?

Comment: See [AngularJS $sanitize Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize).

Comment: @georgeawg It says it is automatically sanitized when you use ng-bind-html.